# Update a php variable within the same page with reloading and don't change previous variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page where I have an items cost i.e total cost and grand-total cost. There are other factors which is dependent of grand-total cost. Using coupon discount, I succeed changing the total and grand-total value using ajax. But the main problem is i cannot manipulate other factors which are dependent of grand-total value as the are assigned through php variables.

I want to reload the page completely and change the php variable which should not affect other values on the same page.

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, you need to post what you've written and clearly point out the part that isn't working properly. It's impossible to answer this vague question.

Comment: Here is the code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199732/how-to-update-total-and-grandtotal-value-in-invoice-page-after-giving-coupon-dis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables might be the solution for the question. But I could not implement it. Instead I used session to store the data from one function of the controller and access the data in another function of same controller and passed the data to the view.

I can easily manipulate the discount coupon value with reloading of the page and change the php variables i.e. total and grand-total values accordingly.